# Dealing with embedded images in markdown blog post with NodeJS (no CMS)

Tags: node.js, markdown, content-management-system, blogs, wysiwyg

I am developing **my own blog website** using NodeJS and Express **with no CMS** and I was wondering how I could **embed images in a markdown blog post** and store the post AND the images on my website. I know that we generally use links in markdown to display images but I don't know how to implement it when writing a post.

The only way I was thinking about to achieve it was to *upload the images on the server* and then *putting links in the post* as I would have done it for external images.

I have no code for this solution because I'm confused. Does anyone have already had to deal with it making its own CMS ?

Comment: "The only way I was thinking about to achieve it was to upload the images on the server and then putting links in the post"—yep, that's what you need to do. Without more information we can't say much more than you already have. There are editor components to make doing this easier, for example. Or you might want to store uploaded images on a service like Amazon S3 or Azure Blob Storage.

Comment: Nice thank you @Chris now I need to figure out how to implement it, I'll search the web for a custom wysiwyg or something like this